# Does a work permit come under D Visa (Post Approval) for Germany?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, german-residents

I want to make an appointment at theGerman Consulate, New Delhi for a work permit. I can't get an appointment before April 25. But when I check with the German Consulate in Banglore, I can see that they have an earlier appointment date for D visa (post approval). I can't find the work permit visa option in the dropdown menu. So are work permit and D visa (post approval) the same? Can I book an appointment under the D Visa (post approval) category?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have no need to book an appointment for D visa (Post Approval) to submit your passport for stamping. You can walk-in to your nearest Germany VFS center and submit your passport along with your visa approval email (Please mention travel date on email printout) and travel health insurance with minimum validity of 1 month from your travel date.